# How to rename file name contains backslash in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I got a tar file, after extracting, there are many files naming like

```
a
b\c
d\e\f
g\h
```

I want to correct their name into files in sub-directories like

```
a
b/c
d/e/f
g/h
```

I face a problem when a variable contains backslash, it will change the original file name. I want to write a script to rename them.

Comment: Although @randomir's answer explains well how to fix this instance of the problem, if might be a good idea to find out what defective program created a non-conformant tar file and beat it up (or replace it).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Parameter expansion is the way to go. You have everything you need in `bash`, no need to use external tools like `find`.

```
$ touch a\\b c\\d\\e
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 ghoti  staff  0 11 Jun 23:13 a\b
-rw-r--r--  1 ghoti  staff  0 11 Jun 23:13 c\d\e
$ for file in *\\*; do
> target="${file//\\//}"; mkdir -p "${target%/*}"; mv -v "$file" "$target"; done
a\b -> a/b
c\d\e -> c/d/e
```

The for loop breaks out as follows:

- `for file in *\\*; do` - select all files whose names contain backslashes
- `target="${file//\\//}";` - swap backslashes for forward slashes
- `mkdir -p "${target%/*}";` - create the target directory by stripping the filename from `$target`
- `mv -v "$file" "$target";` - move the file to its new home
- `done` - end the loop.

The only tricky bit here I think is the second line: `${file//\\//}` is an expression of `${var//pattern/replacement}`, where the pattern is an escaped backslash (`\\`) and the replacement is a single forward slash.

Have a look at `man bash` and search for "Parameter Expansion" to learn more about this.

---

Alternately, if you really want to use `find`, you can still take advantage of bash's Parameter Expansion:

```
find . -name '*\\*' -type f \
  -exec bash -c 't="${0//\\//}"; mkdir -p "${t%/*}"; mv -v "$0" "$t"' {} \;
```

This uses `find` to identify each file and process it with an `-exec` option that basically does the same thing as the `for` loop above. One significant difference here is that `find` will traverse subdirectories (limited by the `-maxdepth` option), so ... be careful.

Comment: I agree with your replacement (e.g. `${var//pattern/replacement}`), but funny thing is `${file/\\//}` works as well, it just doesn't agree with the `"Parameter Expansion"` part of `man bash`, but I'm still trying to satisfy myself why it in fact does work. (another fine mystery...)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, per your comment on the other answer, I've been trying to figure out why `${file//\\//}` doesn't agree. The way I'm reading the bit about Pattern Substitution, the first slash identifies the start of the pattern, the second slash at the start of the pattern causes all matches to be found, and the third slash identifies the start of the string. Everything from there to the `}` is the string. There's nothing saying that a slash remains special within the replacement string. I'd love to hear your take on this!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: To add to ghoti's comment: _In practice_, the string following the `/` after the pattern is treated as if it were an _unquoted_ string in terms of _backlash handling_  and _variable/arithmetic expansion and command substitution_ (yet neither word splitting nor globbing are applied), which is why `/` and `\/` are treated the same (try `echo /` and `echo \/` - both produce just `/`).
In Bash 4+ you can be more explicit by using _quoting_ in the replacement string (in the _pattern_ part you can do that even in Bash 3.x), in which case the usual rules apply: `${file//\\/'/'}`.

Comment: @ghoti I was scratching my head. Where's Charles when you need him `:)`. The way it was originally written in the OP's answer, `${file/\\//}`, tells me that only the 1st occurrence of `'\'` would be replaced with `/`, but that's not the case. The remainder makes sense `\\\` as a literal `\` replaced by a `/`. I'm concerned that I'm missing something simple that would explain the discrepancy, But I can't find it to save my life.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: `${file/\\//}` indeed only replaces the _first_ occurrence. Try `file='a\b\c'; echo "${file/\\//}"`, which should yield `a/b\c`, both in Bash 3.x and 4.x.

Comment: Ahh! Thank you! I was having an `I D 10 T` moment. Yes, all is well in the world. I had miscopied the string and was trying to prove to myself why `b='d/e/f/g'; p=${b/\\//}; echo $p` worked. (`I D 10 T` altogether is `idiot`) If the slashes are turned the right way, all is well, `b='d\e\f\g'; p=${b/\\//}; echo $p`. Forest-for-the-trees....

Answer (score 2):

Renaming a file with backslashes is simple: `mv 'a\b' 'newname'` (just quote it), but you'll need more than that.

You need to:

- find all files with a backslash (e.g. `a\b\c`)
- split path from filename (e.g. `a\b` from `c`)
- create a complete path (e.g. `a/b`, dir `b` under dir `a`)
- move the old file under a new name, under a created path (e.g. rename `a\b\c` to file named `c` in dir `a/b`)

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -name '*\\*' | while read f; do
    base="${f%\\*}"
    file="${f##*\\}"
    path="${base//\\//}"
    mkdir -p "$path"
    mv "$f" "$path/$file"
done
```

(Edit: correct handling of filenames with spaces)

Comment: Why have you written `"${base/\\//}"`? I ask because I would write it as `"${base//\\/\/}"` per the `${parameter/pattern/string}` definition in `man bash` to insure `"all matches of pattern are replaced with string"`. Both work (and even `"${base//\\//}"`), I always like less typing, do you have a reference for why you have written it the way you have? Even taking `"Quote Removal"` into consideration, I'm still puzzled.

Comment: `find` already have `-exec` option, why don't use it. That'll be simpler and faster than parsing the output with `for`

Comment: `"${base/\\//}"` only replaces the _first_ `\ ` in the path.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, you still need functionality that isn't available in `find` to strip the filename from the target path, create the directory, and issue the `mv`. While you could get the results you need in 3x the code in POSIX shell, everything you need to do this efficiently and with minimal typing is available in bash. If bash is available anyway, why not use it?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, @mklement0, regarding a single slash in pattern subs expr -- it was a typo. To replace all pattern matches, two slashes ``//`` are, of course, required.